# Chained Through Time Implementation

Tags: optaplanner

I have been developing a project that is similar to the task assigning project which uses the chained through time pattern. I have a difficulty comparator that prioritizes the tasks that must be finished earlier. My problem is that whenever a new entity is added to the chain, it's added to the top, pushing down the tasks that must be done earlier.
Is that supposed to happen? or is my implementation bad?
This is my code in the listener. It's basically the same as in the task assigning project.

```
protected void updateStartTime(ScoreDirector scoreDirector,Calcado calcado){
    CalcadoA calcadoAnterior = calcado.getCalcadoAnterior();
    Calcado shadowCalcado = calcado;
    Integer previousEndTime = (calcadoAnterior == null ? null : calcadoAnterior.getEndTime());
    Integer startTime = previousEndTime;
    

    while (shadowCalcado != null && !Objects.equals(shadowCalcado.getStartTime(), startTime)) {
        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(shadowCalcado, "startTime");
        shadowCalcado.setStartTime(startTime);
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(shadowCalcado, "startTime");
        previousEndTime = shadowCalcado.getEndTime();
        shadowCalcado = shadowCalcado.getNextCalcado();
        startTime = previousEndTime;
    }
```

I have tried changing it to this...

```
protected void updateStartTime(ScoreDirector scoreDirector,Calcado calcado) {
    CalcadoA calcadoAnterior = calcado.getCalcadoAnterior();
    Calcado shadowCalcado = calcado;
    Integer previousEndTime = (calcadoAnterior == null ? null : calcadoAnterior.getEndTime());
    Integer startTime = previousEndTime;
    
    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(shadowCalcado, "startTime");
    shadowCalcado.setStartTime(startTime);
    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(shadowCalcado, "startTime");
}
```

but I end up getting a score corruption error.

```
  The entity (Calcado{ 472 descricao= calcado22 tempoInicial: 2  Maquina{nome='Pos 1'}'})'s shadow variable (Calcado.startTime)'s corrupted value (1) changed to uncorrupted value (2) after all VariableListeners were triggered without changes to the genuine variables.
Maybe the VariableListener class (StartTimeUpdatingVariableListener) for that shadow variable (Calcado.startTime) forgot to update it when one of its sources changed.
```

Basically my goal is to whenever a entity is added to the chain, to be added to the end of the chain instead of the top.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's suppose to happen.

An entity isn't really added to a chain, that's a side effect.
It's inserted after another entity or anchor. That entity or anchor is already in a chain, so it implies that the entity is also added to a chain.

Why does that matter? Well, given a chain of `[Anchor-A, Entity-A1, Entity-A2, Entity-A3]`, OptaPlanner can choose to add an `Entity-X` after Anchor-A, Entity-A1, Entity-A2 **or** Entity-A3, resulting in 4 different possible new solution states. It will pick the best one. Turn on TRACE logging to see that happen.

Comment: So there would be no way, taking the example that you gave me, to make sure that in construction phase the Entity-X is inserted after Entity-A3?